# parsing jenkins console output according to test cases; page crash while loading consoleOutput

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a job in jenkins to run a few Python test suites and generates the console output. Is there any way I can get the logs in jenkins separated by my test cases in a particular test suite? My page always crashes when I try to load the full console output because of loc > 200k lines.

I can't use JUnit/testing format because using pyats framework already.

My console output is something like this :

```
Ta-1: test1
|-- Setup                                                          
|   |-- a
<console-op>                                                      
|   |-- b  
<console-op>                                                  
|   `-- c                                                    
|-- test1                                                  
|   |-- initial_setup                                                   
|   |-- a                                                  
|   |-- b
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "2lac" means, but I assume it means there is so much output that the page times out when loading.

I would never output that much to the console (in fact, I have a rule that I enforce that says "no job will produce more than 5mb of text").

Instead, I would output all that text to file, and then have a script that parses that output to whatever format you need.

```
example:
pyats [args] > huge_output.txt
my_super_cool_parser.py --file huge_output.txt
```

Something like that.

Comment: yes, 2lac is the console output lines. Actually this is for QA purpose, my automation suite runs and produces all these output and console logs, I need them to debug.Could you please suggest something that could separate out logs in jenkins according to my test case.

Comment: The output would not be lost, it will just be saved to a file. It will not be in the console output, because I suspect it is too much output for jenkins.  I'm not sure I can help. Maybe pasting the job's config.xml file?  If the job is run via a bash script, you can do what I suggested (writing a parsing script to parse the huge output)